# How do I email all users and their relevant domains in a UNIX system?

Tags: email, unix

I need to mail all users on my shared hosting platform.
I need to be able to do this on a regular basis.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Just all the local mail spools of all local users, or do they have external addresses you need to email?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
echo "message" | mailx -s "notify" `grep -v '#' /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/&@localhost/' | tr  '\n' ' '`
```

Mails `message` with subject `notify` to all local users in the system. You can add this to `cron(1)` and use different mail addresses from a file:

```
echo "message" | mailx -s "notify" `cat emaillist.txt`
```